# Install ncdf4 R package with shell script

Tags: shell, package-management, r

I am trying to install the `ncdf4` R package into a remote machine by using an R script ran by a shell script.

I tried to install other packages and it works fine but with the `ncdf4` package it doesn't.

My R script is the following:

```
install.packages('ncdf4', repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

The output of the shell script is:

```
^LInstalling package into ‘/my/directory/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/ncdf4_1.16.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 121420 bytes (118 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 118 KB

* installing *source* package ‘ncdf4’ ...
** package ‘ncdf4’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure.ac: starting
checking for nc-config... no
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error, nc-config not found or not executable.  This is a script that comes with the
netcdf library, version 4.1-beta2 or later, and must be present for configuration
to succeed.

If you installed the netcdf library (and nc-config) in a standard location, nc-config
should be found automatically.  Otherwise, you can specify the full path and name of
the nc-config script by passing the --with-nc-config=/full/path/nc-config argument
flag to the configure script.  For example:

./configure --with-nc-config=/sw/dist/netcdf4/bin/nc-config

Special note for R users:
-------------------------
To pass the configure flag to R, use something like this:

R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-nc-config=/home/joe/bin/nc-config" ncdf4

where you should replace /home/joe/bin etc. with the location where you have
installed the nc-config script that came with the netcdf 4 distribution.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ncdf4’
* removing ‘/my/directory/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/ncdf4’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpJLxXFq/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("ncdf4", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org") :
  installation of package ‘ncdf4’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(ncdf4) : there is no package called ‘ncdf4’
Execution halted
```

Did you come across this issue before?
Any suggestion?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `netcdf-*` library, although I am not exactly sure which one.

`sudo apt install netcdf-*` should work if you use apt as your package manager.

Comment: `netcdf-dev` most likely. and `netcdf-devel` for RedHat/Centos